# Is there a way to get the grand total of averages in a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a PivotTable in excel that shows the time estimated to perform several actions compared to the time it actually took. The times are "averages" taken from a separate table of data on another sheet. They are averages because they are repeat entries, so I can't sum them or the data will be incorrect.

I am now trying to compare the total estimated time to the total actual time. I need to sum the averages, but this doesn't seem to be an option in Excel.

[A screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24zJu.png)

The last row is the grand total. Excel shows the averages of the data (I don't want this). Any ideas on how to find the sum of the averages? The table is created with VBA and I am comfortable with a VBA trick.

I don't have PowerPivot and haven't pursued it further because I can't find anything online that shows that it would provide this feature.

Comment: Power Pivot *would* provide that option for you.

Comment: You can add a "count" data column and multiply each average by its corresponding count to get the total for all repeats.  Or if the number of repeats is always the same then just multiply the total of the averages by that number.

Comment: @Tim Williams But I don't need to find the sum, I need to be able to manipulate the Grand Total row to sum them for me. I will try to pursue Power Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're flexible on formatting, then you can just put a sum formula above the pivot columns.

[image]